# White space issue on side-by-side proportional-width divs

Tags: css, html

I currently have two side-by-side divs, each set to the width of the page so that I can scroll sideways. The right-hand div needs to peek exactly 40px over into the left side so it's visible on page-load. I've managed (with a lot of help) to get that part fine - the issue now is that there is a 40px gap between the edge of the right-hand div and the edge of the page - illustrated below:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUWqE/1/)

Any ideas on how to get rid of it? Thanks a lot for any help. The 'peek' area has to stay exactly 40px, so using percentages seems to be an issue.  Oh, and for an example of how this would look in vertical form, here's an [example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zdJXq/)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're container has 200% width and is causing the expanding problem.

You need to reduce its size. It's a bit difficult because your width are in % and your negative offset is in px.

What you could do is change the offset to percentage and take that out of the container. 
You will also need to use margin-left rather than left.

This works for me in chrome inspector:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 199%;  /* change here */
  position: relative;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%; 
  background-color:cyan;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -1%; /* and here */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hUyBq/

**Edit: ** 1% is an example, you might want more. update the wrapper accordingly

**Edit: ** Solution using JS: http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/wP4zb/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I've tried used a similar method, but it means that the 'peek' area changes depending on window size and I would much prefer it to stay fixed as it's going to have a small image and text in on it.

Comment: @mattmouth Would you be willing to use some js to help out?

Comment: I'm not totally against it, though I haven't much idea what I'm doing when it comes to js. If you can find a solution though I'd probably try implement it, sure.

Comment: There was a problem saving my fiddle somehow.. i've re-updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you fake it like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NUWqE/4/)**?

I moved the scroll right block (`<p>scroll right --></p>`) outside of the wrapper (you didn't mention if that needed to be there). Then I applied the same color to the wrapper and added `overflow:auto;` to it.

Comment: It does the job of removing the white space, which is good. The problem is the text in the blue area ("RIGHT") gets cut off. I'm wanting the left edge of the blue div to be on the very edge of the page after scrolling over. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: You mean part of the word "right" is cut off? I see that in your example too. If that's what you mean, couldn't you adjust the font? Otherwise I'm not understanding what you mean by the text getting cut off.

Comment: Yeah, it is happening in the example because of the white space on the right. If that were gone, the div would line up with the window. Check out the second example I posted, the vertical illustration. I basically want the second div to act like that, which would mean the text is visible like that in both.